# Remove white spaces in character strings

Tags: r

I have a data frame imported from a text file :

```
                      dateTime contract bidPrice askPrice bidSize askSize
1 Tue Dec 14 05:12:20 PST 2010     CLF1        0        0       0       0
2 Tue Dec 14 05:12:20 PST 2010     CLG1        0        0       0       0
3 Tue Dec 14 05:12:20 PST 2010     CLH1        0        0       0       0
4 Tue Dec 14 05:12:20 PST 2010     CLJ1        0        0       0       0
5 Tue Dec 14 05:12:20 PST 2010     NGF1        0        0       0       0
6 Tue Dec 14 05:12:20 PST 2010     NGG1        0        0       0       0
  lastPrice lastSize volume
1         0        0      0
2         0        0      0
3         0        0      0
4         0        0      0
5         0        0      0
6         0        0      0
```

I try to create a subset for all rows where contract = CLF1 but get the following error:

```
> clf1 <- data.frame(subset(train2, as.character(contract="CLF1")))
Error in as.character(contract = "CLF1") : 
  supplied argument name 'contract' does not match 'x'
```

I try to find how many characters are in the cell:

```
> f <-as.character(train2[1,2])
> nchar(f)
[1] 5
```

I assumed this is due to a leading or trailing space so I try the following:

```
> clf1 <- data.frame(subset(train2, as.character(contract=" CLF1")))
Error in as.character(contract = " CLF1") : 
  supplied argument name 'contract' does not match 'x'
> clf1 <- data.frame(subset(train2, as.character(contract="CLF1 ")))
Error in as.character(contract = "CLF1 ") : 
  supplied argument name 'contract' does not match 'x'
```

Again no luck, so here I am.  Any suggestions would be great. Thank you.

EDIT:

```
> clf1 <- subset(train2, contract == "CLF1")
> head(clf1)
[1] dateTime  contract  bidPrice  askPrice  bidSize   askSize   lastPrice lastSize 
[9] volume   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are using the incorrect syntax in `subset`. Try this instead:

```
subset(train2, contract == "CLF1")
```

So you shouldn't be coercing the subset expression to a character, and you also need to use the `==` equality operator, not `=`. You should read `?subset` and look at the difference between the examples there and your code.

Although your field may indeed contain leading spaces, in which case it would be good to try:

```
subset(train2, contract == " CLF1")
```

or when you read the file in using `read.table` you can use the `strip.white` argument to strip whitespace.

Comment: The second one with the leading space did it.  Thank you very much!